# Difference between getCause and getNextException in SQLException?

Tags: java, jdbc

Looking at the [SQLException javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html), there seems to be an overlap between `getCause` and `getNextException`. The first returns a Throwable, but otherwise they seem to be pretty much interchangeable.

What is the difference between the two? When developing a JDBC driver, are there guidelines about when to choose one over the other as the exception chaining mechanism?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The method `getCause()` gives you the cause - if any - of that specific `SQLException`. On the other hand during processing it is entirely possible that multiple exceptions occur, think of batch processing, serverside errors for multiple query parameters (eg too long, conversion errors etc).

These multiple exceptions are on the same level (they are not each others cause), so they are added to a chain of `SQLException`s. The head of this chain is the exception that is thrown. To get to the other `SQLException`s in the chain, you use `getNextException()`. Eg

```
try {
   // Something that produces multiple SQLExceptions
} catch (SQLException e) {
   SQLException current = e;
   do {
      // do something with current
   } while ((current = current.getNextException()) != null)
}
```

On the other hand, a `SQLException` also has a method [`public Iterator<Throwable> iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#iterator%28%29) (introduced in Java 6/JDBC4), this iterates over each `SQLException` and their causes before proceeding to the next `SQLException` in the chain.

Answer (score 5):

A SQL operation can fail for several independent reasons - for example, you could be trying to update multiple rows, and three rows don't exist. Those three failures are independent - none of them causes the other one. That's where `getNextException()` is appropriate - and you can use `setNextException()` when constructing the exception.

On the other hand, if the whole operation has failed *because* there was an `IOException` when talking to the database, that's a root cause - the only reason the `SQLException` occurred was because the `IOException` occurred. That's where `getCause()` is appropriate - pass in the cause to the constructor when you create the `SQLException`.

Answer (score 5):

The execution of an SQL statement may produce many SQLExceptions, in particular if it's a batch statement. Suppose you insert 10 rows in one batch and two fail: you'll get one exception that tells you the batch failed and that you should use the getNextException method to access the details. This may depend on the database driver though.

The cause of an exception is used when wrapping one exception in another, for example to throw an application specific exception that was caused by an IO or SQLException.